# Can't get value of user field in Drupal's node tpl (using field_get_items)

Tags: drupal-7

I'm trying to print the node author's first name in a node's template but I can't get it to work.

This is what I have tried:

```
$author = user_load($node->uid);
$values = field_get_items('user', $author, 'field_first_name');
$value  = $values[0]['value'];
dpm($value);
print $value;
```

`dpm($value)` prints the correct value but `print $value` doesn't print anything.
The same happens with `dpm($values)` - it displays an array with one array element [0] containing the correct elements (value, format, safe value). If I try `print_r($values)` it doesn't print anything.

Also, the following loop gives me an "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" warning.

```
foreach ($values as $first_name) {
    print '<pre>';
    print $first_name['value'];
    print $first_name['safe_value'];
    print '</pre>';
}
```

If I try to access the value directly I get an "Undefined index: und in include()" notice.

```
 $author       = user_load($node->uid);
 $direct_value = $author->field_first_name['und']['0']['value'];
 print $direct_value;
```

How can I print this variable? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works now. I didn't change anything and I have no idea what happened.
Sorry guys and thanks anyway.